# Delete operation in CGridView in yii.

Tags: php, yii, yii-widgets

I am using CGRidVeiw to list my records from database,
In each records I have an edit and delete button.Everthing is working fn9 other than the delete operation,actually its is showing an error after clicking the delete icon,but its still working.Below is the snap of what it actually look like,

[image]

After hitting refresh its not showing the record.
I have my view and contoller as below.

//contoller

```
  public function actionDeleteEmployer() {

        $model = new AdminDeleteEmployer();

        if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
            $id = $_GET['id'];
        }

        $query = "DELETE FROM user,jobs USING user INNER JOIN jobs ON jobs.user_id = user.id WHERE user.id =$id";

        Yii::app()->db->createCommand($query)->queryAll();

         $this->redirect('admin/site/ManageEmployers');
    }
```

///view

## Manage Employers

```
<div class="form">
    <?php
    $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
        'dataProvider' => $model->search(),
        'ajaxUpdate'=>false,
        //   'filter' => $model,
        'columns' => array(
            array(
                'name' => ' Employer ID',
                'type' => 'raw',
                'value' => 'CHtml::encode($data->id)',
                'htmlOptions' => array('style' => 'width:90px;', 'class' => 'zzz'),
            // 'filter'=>'false' /* for hiding filter boxes */
            ),
            array(
                'name' => 'Created On',
                'type' => 'raw',
                'value' => 'CHtml::encode( date("m-d-Y",strtotime($data->created)))',
                'htmlOptions' => array('style' => 'width:90px;', 'class' => 'zzz'),
            // 'filter'=>'false' /* for hiding filter boxes */
            ),
            array(
                'name' => 'Account Name',
                'type' => 'raw',
                'value' => 'CHtml::encode($data->name)',
                'htmlOptions' => array('style' => 'width:90px;', 'class' => 'zzz'),
            // 'filter'=>'false' /* for hiding filter boxes */
            ),
            array(
                'name' => 'Email',
                'type' => 'raw',
                'value' => 'CHtml::encode($data->email)',
                'htmlOptions' => array('style' => 'width:90px;', 'class' => 'zzz'),
            // 'filter'=>'false' /* for hiding filter boxes */
            ),
            array(
                'name' => 'Last Active On',
                'type' => 'raw',
                'value' => 'CHtml::encode( date("m-d-Y",strtotime($data->modified)))',
                'htmlOptions' => array('style' => 'width:90px;', 'class' => 'zzz'),
            // 'filter'=>'false' /* for hiding filter boxes */
            ),
            array(
                'class' => 'CButtonColumn',
                'deleteConfirmation' => 'Are you sure you want to delte this item?',
                'template' => '{view}{delete}',
                'buttons' => array(
                    'view' => array('label' => 'view',
                        'url' => 'Yii::app()->controller->createUrl("ViewEmployerActivity",array("id"=>$data["id"]))'),
                    'delete' => array('label' => 'delete',
                        'url' => 'Yii::app()->controller->createUrl("DeleteEmployer",array("id"=>$data["id"]))'),
                )
            )
        ),
    ));
    ?>

</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Yii::app()->db->createCommand($query)->execute();

Comment: ok...thanks @tinybyte,It worked

Comment: i think you should `Yii::app()->end()` it

Comment: I have written like   $this->redirect(array('manageemployers'));

Comment: or `$this->redirect(array('admin'))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

redirect to admin action

```
Yii::app()->db->createCommand($query)->execute();
$this->redirect(array('admin'))
```

Comment: this is the answer  Yii::app()->db->createCommand($query)->execute();